# Why do I need to use count -=1 in the following code?

Tags: java

When creating the following function, in order to get a correct answer I have to add "count-=1" line, otherwise the answer gets skewed by 1.

```
public int countCTG(String dna) {
    int count = 0;
    int firstOccurrence = dna.indexOf("CTG");

    if (firstOccurrence != -1) {
        count +=1;
        while (dna.indexOf("CTG", firstOccurrence) != -1 && firstOccurrence != -1) {
            count +=1;
            firstOccurrence = dna.indexOf("CTG", firstOccurrence+3);
        }
        count -=1;
    }
    else {
        count = 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I managed to get this function working, however could you please help me understand the logic behind it? The count variable was initialized originally to 0 and if a string,for example, contains one instance of "CTG" it will be already counted in by "count +=1" line. Wouldn't count -=1 reset this variable back to 0?

Answer (score 1):

You need the -1 because of the +1 before the loop: the first iteration of the while loop counts the already-found occurrence again.

An easier solution is like so:

```
int count = 0;
int skip = "CTG".length();
int current = -skip;
while ((current = dna.indexOf("CTG", current + skip)) >= 0) {
  ++count;
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because you're not updating `firstOccurrence` after your first search** -- i.e. you're searching twice from the start (`.indexOf("CTG")`) before starting to search from the previous result (`.indexOf("CTG", prevResultIndex + 3)`).

---

Also note that:

- you don't have to search once before the while loop
- the else clause is redundant
- you're calling `.indexOf` twice as many times as you actually need
- the `firstOccurrence+3` is a liability, you'll forget to update the offset when the string changes and it will be hard to track down. Store the searched-for string in one place, and compute its length instead of hardcoding it.

---

*EDIT: Well @AndyTurner rewrote it for you, but try to see how each one of the listed points come into reaching that result*